# sqlite version of vlookup

Tags: sqlite, vlookup

is there a way in sqlite to do the equivalent of a vlookup? I'm trying to do something like this:
Master table:
ValueA | ValueB | concatValueA&ValueB

Mapping table:
concatValueA&ValueB | mapped Value

final table:
ValueA | ValueB | concatValueA&ValueB | mapped Value

In Excel, I would just do a vlookup.

Is there a way to add the mapped value to a table in sqlite?

I tried this:

```
UPDATE Master Set "mapped Value" = (select mapping."mapped Value" from Master left join mapping on Master.concat = mapping.concat)
```

But this fills sets the mapped Value column entirely equal to the first value from the select statement, but I would like the values to be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the subquery, `Master` does not refer to the row being updated because you have introduced another instance of this table in the FROM clause.

What you want is a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), which needs to refer to a table that is otherwise not directly part of the subquery:

```
UPDATE Master
SET "mapped Value" = (SELECT mapping."mapped Value"
                      FROM mapping
                      WHERE Master.concat = mapping.concat)
```